# Missing PUBKEY in python

Tags: gnupg

I have started coding in Python. Im on ChromeOs with Pycharm. Im getting GPG error while installing flask.Anybody

Tried GOOGLE. tried some commands. No success

root@penguin:/home/singhakj7#  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
E: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.root@penguin:/home/singhakj7# or repository creation and user configuration details.

root@penguin:/home/singhakj7#  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
E: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.root@penguin:/home/singhakj7# or repository creation and user configuration details.